# Know which thread goes to which processor in a Java ForkJoinPool in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, fork-join

**Goal: To know, as I fork off a thread, which processor it's going to land on. Is that possible? Regardless of whether the underlying approach is valid, is there a good answer to that narrow question? Thanks.**

(Right now I need to make a copy of one of our classes for each thread, write to it in that thread and merge them all later. Using a `synchronized` approach is not possible because my Java expert boss thinks it's a bad idea, and after a lot of discussion I agree. If I knew which processor each thread would land on, I would only need to make as many copies of that class as there are processors.)

We use Apache Spark to get our jobs spread across a cluster, but in our application is makes sense to run one big executor and then do some multi-threading of our own out on each machine in the cluster.

I could save a lot of deep copying **if I could know which processor a thread is being sent to, is that possible?** I threw in our code but it's probably more of a conceptual question:

**When I get down to the "do task" part of compute(), can I know which processor it's running on?**

```
public class TholdExecutor extends RecursiveTask<TholdDropEvaluation> {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TholdExecutor.class);

    private List<TholdDropResult> partitionOfN = new ArrayList<>();
    private int coreCount;
    private int desiredPartitionSize; // will be updated by whatever is passed into the constructor per-chromosome
    private TholdDropEvaluation localDropEvaluation; // this DropEvaluation
    private TholdDropResult mSubI_DR;


    public TholdExecutor(List<TholdDropResult> subsetOfN, int cores, int partSize, TholdDropEvaluation passedDropEvaluation, TholdDropResult mDrCopy) {
        partitionOfN = subsetOfN;
        coreCount = cores;
        desiredPartitionSize = partSize;

        // the TholdDropEvaluation needs to be a copy for each thread? It can't be the same one passed to threads ... so ...
        TholdDropEvaluation localDropEvaluation = makeDECopy(passedDropEvaluation); // THIS NEEDS TO BE A DEEP COPY OF THE DROP EVAL!!! NOT THE ORIGINAL!!

        // we never modify the TholdDropResult that is passed in, we just need to read it all on the same JVM/worker, so
        mSubI_DR = mDrCopy; // this is purely a reference and can point to the passed in value (by reference, right?)

    }

    // this makes a deep copy of the TholdDropEvaluation for each thread, we copy the SharingRun's startIndex and endIndex only,
    // as LEG events will be calculated during the subsequent dropComparison. The constructor for TholdDropEvaluation must set
    // LEG events to zero.
    private void makeDECopy(TholdDropEvaluation passedDropEvaluation) {
        TholdDropEvaluation tholdDropEvaluation = new TholdDropEvaluation();

        // iterate through the SharingRuns in the SharingRunList from the TholdDropEval that was passed in
        for (SharingRun sr : passedDropEvaluation.getSharingRunList()) {
            SharingRun ourSharingRun = new SharingRun();
            ourSharingRun.startIndex = sr.startIndex;
            ourSharingRun.endIndex = sr.endIndex;

            tholdDropEvaluation.addSharingRun(ourSharingRun);
        }
        return tholdDropEvaluation
    }

    @Override
    protected TholdDropEvaluation compute() {

        int simsToDo = partitionOfN.size();
        UUID tag = UUID.randomUUID();

        long computeStartTime = System.nanoTime();

        if (simsToDo <= desiredPartitionSize) {
            logger.debug("IN MULTI-THREAD compute() --- UUID {}:Evaluating partitionOfN sublist length", tag, simsToDo);

            // job within size limit, do the task and return the completed TholdDropEvaluation
            // iterate through each TholdDropResult in the sub-partition and do the dropComparison to the refernce mSubI_DR,
            // writing to the copy of the DropEval in tholdDropEvaluation
            for (TholdDropResult currentResult : partitionOfN) {

                mSubI_DR.dropComparison(currentResult, localDropEvaluation);

            }
        } else {

            // job too large, subdivide and call this recursively
            int half = simsToDo / 2;
            logger.info("Splitting UUID = {}, half is {} and simsToDo is {}", tag, half, simsToDo );
            TholdExecutor nextExec = new TholdExecutor(partitionOfN.subList(0, half), coreCount, desiredPartitionSize, tholdDropEvaluation, mSubI_DR);
            TholdExecutor futureExec = new TholdExecutor(partitionOfN.subList(half, simsToDo), coreCount, desiredPartitionSize, tholdDropEvaluation, mSubI_DR);
            nextExec.fork();
            TholdDropEvaluation futureEval = futureExec.compute();
            TholdDropEvaluation nextEval = nextExec.join();
            tholdDropEvaluation.merge(futureEval);
            tholdDropEvaluation.merge(nextEval);
        }

        logger.info("{} Compute time is {} ns",tag, System.nanoTime() - computeStartTime);

        // NOTE: this was inside the else block in Rob's example, but don't we want it outside the block so it's returned
        // whether
        return tholdDropEvaluation;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are asking your question at a too low level by assuming you have made the right choices so far. This may be true, but this may not. Could you start with a more high level problem statement i.e. clearly stating your goal ?

Comment: Well for the sake of this question let's assume we have made the right choices ... I'd have to explain a complicated genomic analysis library to explain why a single executor is desirable ... suffice it to say it would move us AWAY from an MVCE when a simple MVCE is not needed or really possible. [A MVCE, if really needed, would look like this Oracle tutorial for fork-join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html). I appreciate your response but will just let the question stand, and I will edit the question to state the current goal more clearly. Thank you!

Comment: `makeDECopy` seems to be doing nothing. It will make a copy, which is a local variable not referenced by any other object. It will be GCed shortly after exiting the constructor. What I was looking for is an evidence That the algorithm mutates this object, which could justify the need for a deep copy. Bad copy paste ? It is referenced and mutated from `compute`.

Comment: Good point, a bug, I need to be returning it, a line I omitted from the copy here but is in the original code. But not the main question. So if anyone has an answer for the main question, which really has nothing to do with my code, I'd appreciate it very much!

Comment: Well although I'm not a multithreading guru, I think the answer is no and the fact there is no answer yet may be an answer in itself. You don't ever know which processor will execute your instruction do you ? It may not be true in low-level languages but I would be astonished that you can get such guarantees in a high-level language running in a VM and not directly in the OS. This is even more complicated in the context of a distributed job

Comment: The OS might decide to pause a thread mid-execution, move it to another core before resuming. Depending on such low-level information is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Run this command `watch -tdn0.5 ps -mo pid,tid,%cpu,psr -p \`pgrep java\``, and watch the PSR column changes.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I tend to think you are correct in your assessment. Interesting command line, of course the point is if I knew (or could control) which processor was going to get a specific task, and I could safely assume each task lined up on a processor would be executed in a serial fashion (per processor) I could squeeze out more speed and less copies of this TholdDropEvaluation. Our process requires 100 million x 2000 comparisons, estimated to take about 20 days on a three-core cluster and our larger cluster is not available this summer (university medical environment), so every bit counts!

Comment: I wonder if there's a different Stack Exchange site more suited to this question? Maybe programmers?

Comment: And one thing, @Dici said (I thought you were the same person as Dikei LOL my bad) " This is even more complicated in the context of a distributed job" ... actually not true ... each machine in the cluster is running the anonymous function from a Spark rdd.foreachPartition and can be viewed locally as just another Java programming trying to max out all the processors :)

Comment: please keep in mind that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat who is cross posting? If you are criticizing something it would be nice to say what. If you mean my suggestion that maybe this is a question for programmers.se, I meant for some moderator to move it if they felt it appropriate. This question has drawn a lot of comments and no answers so I am going to assume the answer to my question is "no." Thanks for your feedback, I am going to flag my own question now to be moved to a site where it might see an answer.

Comment: Controlling thread->core mappings is normally very platform dependent, not something I'd try doing in Java. Given that it seems what you actually want is a 1:1 mapping between an object and threads, i.e. one instance per thread you're probably looking for [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) storage

Comment: @Flexo thanks, if you had a reference to that and posted an answer I'd accept it, I was forgetting that the JVM prevents us from managing hardware in that way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could figure out where a thread would run *initially* there's no reason to assume it would live on that processor/core for the rest of its life. In all probability for any task big enough to be worth the cost of spawning a thread it won't, so you'd need to control where it ran completely to offer that level of assurance.

As far as I know there's no standard mechanism for controlling mappings from threads to processor cores inside Java. Typically that's known as "thread affinity" or "processor affinity". On Windows and Linux for example you can control that using:

- Windows: [`SetThreadAffinityMask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Linux: [`sched_setaffinity`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) or [`pthread_setaffinity_np`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html)

so in theory you could write some C and JNI code that allowed you to abstract this enough on the Java hosts you cared about to make it work.

That feels like the wrong solution to the real problem you seem to be facing, because you end up withdrawing options from the OS scheduler, which potentially doesn't allow it to make the smartest scheduling decisions causing total runtime to increase. Unless you're pushing an unusual workload **and** modelling/querying processor information/topology down to the level of NUMA and shared caches it ought to do a better job of figuring out where to run threads for most workloads than you could. Your JVM typically runs a large number of additional threads besides just the ones you explicitly create from after `main()` gets called. Additionally I wouldn't like to promise anything about what the JVM you run today (or even tomorrow) might decide to do on its own about thread affinity.

Having said that it seems like the underlying problem is that you want to have one instance of an object per thread. Typically that's much easier than predicting where a thread will run and then manually figuring out a mapping between N processors and M threads at any point in time. Usually you'd use "thread local storage" (TLS) to solve this problem.

Most languages provide this concept in one form or another. In Java this is provided via the [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) class. There's an example in the linked document given:

> ```
>  public class ThreadId {
>      // Atomic integer containing the next thread ID to be assigned
>      private static final AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger(0);
>
>      // Thread local variable containing each thread's ID
>      private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> threadId =
>          new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
>              @Override protected Integer initialValue() {
>                  return nextId.getAndIncrement();
>          }
>      };
>
>      // Returns the current thread's unique ID, assigning it if necessary
>      public static int get() {
>          return threadId.get();
>      }
>  }
> ```

Essentially there are two things you care about:

1. When you call `get()` it returns the value (Object) belonging to the current thread
2. If you call get in a thread which currently has nothing it will call `initialValue()` you implement, which allows you to construct or obtain a new object.

So in your scenario you'd probably want to deep copy the initial version of some local state from a read-only global version.

One final point of note: if your goal is to divide and conquer; do some work on lots of threads and then merge all their results to one answer the merging part is often known as a reduction. In that case you might be looking for [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) which is probably the most well known form of parallelism using reductions.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the pointer to mapReduce, certainly given that I am using Spark I would normally use the form of mapReduce in Spark ... but we have found it's more efficient to let Spark split jobs to multiple machines and manage the parallelism ourselves on each machine. Thanks again for an awesome answer that really gets me thinking, very thankful student here +1

Comment: Never having used it I'm surprised that Spark wouldn't have some kind of smarter way of dividing tasks with a hierarchy based on topologies that gets you the desired behaviour in a neater, less DIY way.

Comment: It does, Spark is pretty cool, generally speaking ..reason for all the gyrations is because the Java libraries we are working with are very much not written with functional programming in mind, thus Spark has not been a great fit. If I had this all to do over again I would have started with Java OpenMPI / RMI. It's a little longer story than that, but we often need to write in place vs. mapping things, and we only allow Spark to make one big executor per machine. That executor won't take advantage of all processors so we fork-join on the back end. Interesting use case, not a great example haha